# How to check if a string has more than 1 integer, separated by a comma

Tags: javascript, string, integer

How can I use javascript to check and see if a string has more than 1 integer?

ie.

```
var x = 1,15,30 { returns true }


var x = 13 { returns false }
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't make sense. Where is the string? Did you mean to write `var x = '1,15,30'; // returns true` ? What is the format of the string? Are numbers always delimited by `,`? Can there be floats (e.g. `1.5`)? You are not providing enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex to search for groups of digits (`\d+`). If the length of all found groups is greater then 1 return true, if not return false.

```js
function moreThenOneNumber(str) {
  return str.match(/\d+/g).length > 1;
}

var x = '1,15,30';
var y = '13';

console.log(moreThenOneNumber(x));

console.log(moreThenOneNumber(y));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all items are integers:

```
function(s){ return s.indexOf(',')!=-1 }
```